# VBA Recordset / Oracle and Excel Connect

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, recordset

I've installed tries recordset in my vba statement. 
Unfortunately he accesses only the first line in my database. Who can help me?
I'm not very good in VBA it's my first porject. I hope someone can help me with my code. Thank you

```
Sub Testbox()

Dim conn, Rs
Dim strSQL As String
Dim auswahl As Integer

auswahl = MsgBox("Die Daten werden geladen", vbOKCancel, "Bitte auswählen")

If auswahl = 1 Then

connstring = "UID=user;PWD=passwort;DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC For Oracle};SERVER=server.WORLD;"
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
With conn
    .ConnectionString = connstring
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Mode = adModeRead
    .Open
End With
Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "select * from table  where logdatum =1507"
Rs.Open strSQL, conn, 3, 3
Range("A2:A5000") = Rs("scanclient")
Range("B2:B500") = Rs("Sum")
Range("C2:C500") = Rs("batchclass")
Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing      

Else
Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to print data from Recordset into worksheet like that:

```
Range("A2:A5000") = Rs("scanclient")
Range("B2:B500") = Rs("Sum")
Range("C2:C500") = Rs("batchclass")
```

You need to replace this code with the below:

```
Dim i As Long: i = 1
Do Until Rs.EOF
    i = i + 1
    Cells(i, 1) = Rs("scanclient")
    Cells(i, 2) = Rs("Sum")
    Cells(i, 3) = Rs("batchclass")
    Call Rs.MoveNext
Loop
```